# Which one is correct to use?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I'm confused with a sentence that would ask for concerns in business writing.
Which of the below sentences is correct to use:

> Let us know if any concerns.

or

> Let us know concerns if any.

Comment: The verb needs a preposition: "Let us know **of** any concerns." -- the *if* is unnecessary when *any* is used. HTH.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please also visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would write:

> *Please* let us know if *you have* any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use either one.  I will slightly modify your sentences to get something closer:

> 1. Let us know if *you have* any concerns.
> 2. Let us know *your* concerns, if any.